# Filtering traffic by MAC - nftables

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, mac-address, nftables

**TL:DR** : I am building a network tap with a raspberry-pi that must remains **stealth**. I have a bridge (**br0**) between the switch interface (**eth0**) and the workstation (**eth1**).

Here is how i am building it (*open to any suggestion*):

```
# Create a bridge with the name br0
ip link add "$BRIDGE_INT" type bridge 
# Add the eth0 interface to the bridge
ip link set "$WORKSTATION_INT" master "$BRIDGE_INT" 
# Add the eth1 interface to the bridge
ip link set "$SWITCH_INT" master "$BRIDGE_INT"
```

After this process is done, I am plugging the network cables and I can see that my **eth0** is leaking its M.A.C on multiple protocols.

**What I've tested** :

```
nft add table inet filter
nft add chain inet filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 \; }
nft add rule inet filter output ether saddr "$SWITCH_MAC" drop
```

Which still leaks on eth0 DHCP -> ARP -> MDNS.

I've then decided to put a DHCP static address. After multiple tries I've found the right configuration for that (*Open to any suggestion*):

```
/etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet manual
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254

/etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface eth0
    static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
    static routers=192.168.0.1
    static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

This configuration won't query the network for dhcp. But ARP -> MDNS are still leaking.

As this project is aimed to be adaptable, I think the best solution is to drop everything having the SWITCH_MAC. But this doesn't stop traffic from flowing out.

What I've noticed is that my rule is correctly dropping packets with SWITCH_MAC that I send on purpose but doesn't drop what's emitted by the OS.

**CONCLUSION**
The OS is leaking unwanted traffic even though the test traffic is being dropped. I suspect my issue is similar to this one : [Filtering traffic by MAC address with nftables](https://serverfault.com/questions/1087821/filtering-traffic-by-mac-address-with-nftables)
Which is very well explained, but no solution has been found yet.